# Ubuntu 13.04 unable to set keyboard layout

Tags: 13.04, keyboard-layout

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04. When I try to add another keyboard layout (clicking the 'Layout Settings' link in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Typing Tab) the system doesn't respond. Is there another way to add a keyboard layout?

Comment: open the terminal, type `gnome-control-center` then go in **Keyboard Layout** and click on the small "+" icon in the bottom left. Go back to the terminal and past here any error you read on screen.

Comment: I had the following error:
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug


(gnome-control-center:15298): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'com.canonical.indicator.keyboard' is not installed

Comment: If by another layout you mean another language's layout then this might help. I've had issues with chinese keyboard. What i did is go to settings, Language Support, and click install/remove languages button, which brings up menu for desired language. Click apply changes, wait till it all loads, and reboot. As for other suggestions, you could try couple configuration managers, which can be downloaded in Software Center. Just search for keyboard or text input

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a corrupted configuration file. I'd start by reinstalling the gnome control center, that may fix the problem automatically

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

If that doesn't work try also to reinstall the desktop schemas

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gsettings-desktop-schemas
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Done it. Still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following cammand in terminal

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

It will bring out an interactive process where you can select your desired preferences.

Comment: It helped, but the change isn't permanent. When I restart my computer I have to configure again. Also there is no notification which language I am using. I can only switch with Alt+Shift between languages. Thanks